# is this a safe method to secure strings in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I have used this below code to secure string in memory in cpp , here is what I used :

```
        unsigned char data[8]={0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64};
        string sensetive(reinterpret_cast< char const* >(data),8);
        std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(sensetive.begin(), sensetive.end());
        LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();

        // sw will be used in the next part of the code.
```

Is this a safe method to secure strings in c++?

secure means to use any method to make reverse engineer harder : obfuscation ,encryption

in memory,etc.

What is your idea ?

Is there any better way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean _'secure strings'_? `std::string` and `std::wstring` aren't compatible.

Comment: Securing in what way? Obfuscation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : post was edited to add more details.

Comment: @stefan: post was edited to add more details.

Comment: There is no simple way to restrict this. The best way is to only store a encrypted message and to decrypt it at runtime but your decryption algorithm can be found as well. It is practically impossible to hide these strings.

Comment: Your code obfuscates nothing, even from the compiled code it will be easy to extract the sequence you give there `unsigned char data[8]={0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64};`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : so what is your suggestion? thanks.

Comment: @MikeJohanson Stick to stefan's suggestion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: there must be some methods to secure strings. protection is better than nothing. I know that is impossible to secure 100% but i want to increase this percentage from 0% to at least 50%.

Comment: @MikeJohanson A simple [rot-x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) encoding may be ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's find out...

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char data[8]={0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64};
}
```

If we compile the program and look at the generated object code:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp
hexdump -C test
```

Given a couple of minutes, one should be able to spot the password. Can you see it?

```
00000500  75 02 5d c3 ba 00 00 00  00 48 85 d2 74 f4 5d 48  |u.]......H..t.]H|
00000510  89 c6 bf a8 09 60 00 ff  e2 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00  |.....`..........|
00000520  80 3d 81 04 20 00 00 75  11 55 48 89 e5 e8 7e ff  |.=.. ..u.UH...~.|
00000530  ff ff 5d c6 05 6e 04 20  00 01 f3 c3 0f 1f 40 00  |..]..n. ......@.|
00000540  48 83 3d 18 02 20 00 00  74 1e b8 00 00 00 00 48  |H.=.. ..t......H|
00000550  85 c0 74 14 55 bf 60 07  60 00 48 89 e5 ff d0 5d  |..t.U.`.`.H....]|
00000560  e9 7b ff ff ff 0f 1f 00  e9 73 ff ff ff 55 48 89  |.{.......s...UH.|
00000570  e5 c6 45 f0 70 c6 45 f1  61 c6 45 f2 73 c6 45 f3  |..E.p.E.a.E.s.E.|
00000580  73 c6 45 f4 77 c6 45 f5  6f c6 45 f6 72 c6 45 f7  |s.E.w.E.o.E.r.E.|
00000590  64 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3  0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00  |d.....].........|
000005a0  48 89 6c 24 d8 4c 89 64  24 e0 48 8d 2d a7 01 20  |H.l$.L.d$.H.-.. |
000005b0  00 4c 8d 25 98 01 20 00  48 89 5c 24 d0 4c 89 6c  |.L.%.. .H.\$.L.l|
000005c0  24 e8 4c 89 74 24 f0 4c  89 7c 24 f8 48 83 ec 38  |$.L.t$.L.|$.H..8|
000005d0  4c 29 e5 41 89 ff 49 89  f6 48 c1 fd 03 49 89 d5  |L).A..I..H...I..|
000005e0  31 db e8 49 fe ff ff 48  85 ed 74 1a 0f 1f 40 00  |1..I...H..t...@.|
000005f0  4c 89 ea 4c 89 f6 44 89  ff 41 ff 14 dc 48 83 c3  |L..L..D..A...H..|
```

Answer (score 2):

As comments point out, what you're doing obscures nothing from anyone except the people reading your source code.

You can't secure anything that's actually going to face attack until you know something about who's going to be attacking. The more you know about them, the better you can do.  No one can advise you how to "increase this percentage from 0% to at least 50%" until you say 50% of what population?  50% of the population of people competent with a good debugger?  Hundred-million-dollar games have this tendency to show up on the pirate bay, cracked, on launch day.  Anything you can tell your computer to do, everyone else can tell their computer to watch.  If what you're trying to secure is a "secret" embedded in your code, against that population, it's only a question of motivation.